# Remove newline from fgets() input

Tags: c, gcc, printf, newline, fgets

I'm trying to write a very simple program which asks you to type your name and then it greets you. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[30];
    printf("Write your name: ");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    printf("Hello, %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile and run the program the following output is shown (typing the name `John Doe`):

```
Hello, John Doe
. Nice to meet you.
```

At first I was going to use `gets()` which apparently doesn't print the newline charcater, but the compiler (GCC) complained about it:

> the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

How can I remove the newline character from a string entered with `fgets()`?

Comment: An easy way is `strtok(name, "\n");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input **you can check this out.**

Answer (score 6):

Add  this line of code `name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';` After `fgets()`. The `newline` happens because *terminal symbol* in `fgets()` is `\n` not `\0` .So we need it to make it `\0`.

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[30];
    printf("Write your name: ");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';                        // making '\n' '\0'
    printf("Hello, %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
Write your name: world
Hello, world. Nice to meet you.
```

Comment: This works but is risky: what if (for whatever reason) the string does *not* end in a newline?

Comment: This takes linear time to find the end of the string.